# Codeigniter Framework Database Error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am getting the following error in the Codeigniter MVC framework project.

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\citizen\system\database\DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 125

any idea how do I debug this.

Comment: You can start by checking the provided settings for `database.php`

Comment: Did you look here application > config > database.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#manually-connecting-to-a-database once working then autoload the database library

Answer (score 1):

if you go to the 'application/config' directory and open database.php at about line 51 you will see

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'The hostname of your database server';
$db['default']['username'] = 'The username used to connect to the database';
$db['default']['password'] = 'The password used to connect to the database';
$db['default']['database'] = 'The name of the database you want to connect to';
```

Fill in these to match your settings. your hostname will be 'localhost', the rest is what you set at the time.
Hope that helps
Regards
Keith

Answer (score 0):

Just for debugging your problem:

Go to `system/database/mysql/mysql_driver` and in `db_connect` method delete the @ from `@mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, TRUE);`

That will show you what is wrong with the database.